# transfer logic into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help to fix the script.
http://jsfiddle.net/rrnJc/

this is a dynamic list of news. you can scroll through.

the problem that the logic is in the template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in news" ng-show="$index >= currentPosition && $index <= (currentPosition + qntVisibleRecords)">
```

this is not right.

I would like to chtby visible part of the list of news was in the controller (in the function $scope.newsVisible). at the same conclusion in the template design and deliver this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in newsVisible">
    <span class="date">{{item.date}}</span>

    <span class="title">{{item.title}} - {{$index}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your array of news when controller is initialized and each time you call the changeCurrent function and iterate through newsVisible. Possible code could be :

```
$scope.changeCurrent = function(value){
  $scope.currentPosition = $scope.currentPosition + value;
  if($scope.currentPosition < 0 ){
     $scope.currentPosition = 0;
  }
  var end = Math.min($scope.currentPosition + $scope.qntVisibleRecords, $scope.news.length)
  //ensure that you won t slice at an index greater than news.length

  $scope.newsVisible = $scope.news.slice($scope.currentPosition, end);
}
```

BTW you can call this function when the controller initialized in order to init your array of newsVisible.

```
 $scope.changeCurrent($scope.currentPosition);
```

You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/rrnJc/1/